# What is the definition of Lindelöf space?

Tags: general-topology, definition

My definition for "countable set" is a set with the cardinal $\aleph_0$ and "at most countable set" is a set $A$ such that $|A|≦\aleph_0$.

Till now, my definition for Lindelöf space is a topological space which admits a *countable subcover* of a given open cover.

However, i found this this definition is stronger than that in wikipedia.

In wikipedia, Lindelöf is defined as a space which admits a "at most countable subcover" of a given open cover.

Which one is the usual definition?

Comment: Usually when we say something is countable we mean it is finite or countable.  In this case the correct definition is that it admits and at most countable subcover

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your strict definition cannot even be correct: a finite cover does not have a subcover (in the sense of a subset that is still a cover) that is countably infinite. This already suggests that indeed the meaning "countable = finite or countably infinite", is meant.

If one wants to avoid the "problem" (if we can call it that) we could formulate Lindelöf as: for every open cover $\mathcal{U} = \{ U_i : i \in I \}$ of $X$ there is a function $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow I$ such that $X = \cup \{U_{f(n)}: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ (so that $f$ can even pick the same subset every time, e.g.). But this seems a bit overly formal. I'd prefer: for every cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ there is a $\mathcal{U}' \subseteq \mathcal{U}$ that covers $X$ and $\left|\mathcal{U}'\right| \le \aleph_0$. These amount to the same thing.